# DynamoDB Update ExpressionAttributeValues

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

Sample test data:

```
"suppliers" : [
  {
    "supplierName": "xxx supplier"
  }, 
  {
    "supplierName": "zzz supplier"
  }
]
```

Excerpt of UpdateItem Params:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":sA" : {L: [event.suppliers]}
//          ":sA" : {L: event.suppliers}
          }
```

I encounter **"UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in params"**. I tried changing the formatting of the AttributeValues but I get other errors like **"UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'supplierName' found in params"**.

I need help properly defining a list AttributeValue.  Note that the input sample test data may contain x number of supplierName objects and hence defining the keys (ie. '0', '1', etc) in the AttributeValue is also not an option. I also prefer not to use the documentClient version of UpdateItem.

Answer (score 0):

`ExpressionAttributeValues` is about to set a value to the parameter of the update expression, for example:

```
dynamoDb.update({
  TableName: ...,
  Key: ...,
  UpdateExpression: 'set suppliers = :suppliers',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {':suppliers': event.suppliers}
}
```

You have to provide the key to the record and then you can change the `suppliers` attribute.

Comment: The above works for documentClient.update method. I need to know how to properly define an array in the format _"ExpressionAttributeValues": { 
      "string" : { 
         "B": blob,
         "BOOL": boolean,
         "BS": [ blob ],
         "L": [ 
            "AttributeValue"
         ],
         "M": { 
            "string" : "AttributeValue"
         },
         "N": "string",
         "NS": [ "string" ],
         "NULL": boolean,
         "S": "string",
         "SS": [ "string" ]
      }
   },_ This is required if you use TransactWriteItems or UpdateItem.